# Payara server not starting

Tags: java, payara, java-ee-8

I'm trying out some Java EE and I can get my code to run on Glassfish 5.0.1 no problem. I want to run it on Payara but I can only get Payara Micro to work, the full and web-profile both crash and give the following errors that I cant find any info about. The closest related problem I could find told me to try changing my path to Java 8 instead, but that had no effect. Thanks!

```
[2020-09-14T18:59:27.963+0200] [Payara 5.2020.4] [INFO] [NCLS-LOGGING-00009] [javax.enterprise.logging] [tid: _ThreadID=22 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1600102767864] [timeMillis: 1600102767963] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Running Payara Version: Payara Server  5.2020.4 #badassfish (build 817)]]

[2020-09-14T18:59:27.968+0200] [Payara 5.2020.4] [INFO] [NCLS-LOGGING-00010] [javax.enterprise.logging] [tid: _ThreadID=22 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1600102767864] [timeMillis: 1600102767968] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Server log file is using Formatter class: com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.ODLLogFormatter]]

[2020-09-14T18:59:28.508+0200] [Payara 5.2020.4] [INFO] [] [org.glassfish.ha.store.spi.BackingStoreFactoryRegistry] [tid: _ThreadID=22 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1600102767864] [timeMillis: 1600102768508] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Registered fish.payara.ha.hazelcast.store.HazelcastBackingStoreFactoryProxy for persistence-type = hazelcast in BackingStoreFactoryRegistry]]

[2020-09-14T18:59:28.544+0200] [Payara 5.2020.4] [INFO] [] [org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version] [tid: _ThreadID=24 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1600102767870] [timeMillis: 1600102768544] [levelValue: 800] [[
  HV000001: Hibernate Validator 6.1.2.Final]]

[2020-09-14T18:59:33.272+0200] [Payara 5.2020.4] [INFO] [] [fish.payara.nucleus.hazelcast.HazelcastCore] [tid: _ThreadID=23 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1600102767870] [timeMillis: 1600102773272] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Hazelcast Instance Bound to JNDI at payara/Hazelcast]]

[2020-09-14T18:59:33.272+0200] [Payara 5.2020.4] [INFO] [] [fish.payara.nucleus.hazelcast.HazelcastCore] [tid: _ThreadID=23 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1600102767870] [timeMillis: 1600102773272] [levelValue: 800] [[
  JSR107 Caching Provider Bound to JNDI at payara/CachingProvider]]

[2020-09-14T18:59:33.272+0200] [Payara 5.2020.4] [INFO] [] [fish.payara.nucleus.hazelcast.HazelcastCore] [tid: _ThreadID=23 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1600102767870] [timeMillis: 1600102773272] [levelValue: 800] [[
  JSR107 Default Cache Manager Bound to JNDI at payara/CacheManager]]

[2020-09-14T18:59:33.474+0200] [Payara 5.2020.4] [INFO] [NCLS-CORE-00015] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=22 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1600102767864] [timeMillis: 1600102773474] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Shutdown requested
MultiException stack 1 of 2
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.security.KeyStoreException: JCEKS not found
    at org.glassfish.security.services.impl.JCEKSPasswordAliasStore.containsKey(JCEKSPasswordAliasStore.java:169)
    at fish.payara.nucleus.microprofile.config.source.PasswordAliasConfigSource.getValue(PasswordAliasConfigSource.java:100)
    at fish.payara.nucleus.microprofile.config.spi.PayaraConfig.getSourceValue(PayaraConfig.java:183)
    at fish.payara.nucleus.microprofile.config.spi.PayaraConfig.getValueConverted(PayaraConfig.java:166)
    at fish.payara.nucleus.microprofile.config.spi.PayaraConfig.lambda$getValue$1(PayaraConfig.java:161)
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.compute(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1853)
    at fish.payara.nucleus.microprofile.config.spi.PayaraConfig.getValue(PayaraConfig.java:157)
    at fish.payara.nucleus.microprofile.config.spi.PayaraConfig.getValueInternal(PayaraConfig.java:127)
    at fish.payara.nucleus.microprofile.config.spi.PayaraConfig.getOptionalValue(PayaraConfig.java:123)
    at fish.payara.microprofile.healthcheck.HealthCheckService.postConstruct(HealthCheckService.java:139)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.ReflectionHelper.invoke(ReflectionHelper.java:1268)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.postConstructMe(ClazzCreator.java:309)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:351)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:463)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:281)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevelContext.findOrCreate(RunLevelContext.java:65)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2102)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:93)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:67)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.oneJob(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1213)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.run(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1144)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.security.KeyStoreException: JCEKS not found
    at org.glassfish.security.services.impl.JCEKSPasswordAliasStore.pa(JCEKSPasswordAliasStore.java:103)
    at org.glassfish.security.services.impl.JCEKSPasswordAliasStore.containsKey(JCEKSPasswordAliasStore.java:167)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: java.security.KeyStoreException: JCEKS not found
    at java.security.KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.java:851)
    at com.sun.enterprise.security.store.PasswordAdapter.loadKeyStore(PasswordAdapter.java:131)
    at com.sun.enterprise.security.store.PasswordAdapter.<init>(PasswordAdapter.java:110)
    at org.glassfish.security.services.impl.JCEKSPasswordAliasStore.pa(JCEKSPasswordAliasStore.java:101)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: JCEKS KeyStore not available
    at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:159)
    at java.security.Security.getImpl(Security.java:697)
    at java.security.KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.java:848)
    ... 31 more
MultiException stack 2 of 2
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: post construct on fish.payara.microprofile.healthcheck.HealthCheckService
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:369)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:463)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:281)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevelContext.findOrCreate(RunLevelContext.java:65)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2102)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:93)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:67)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.oneJob(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1213)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.run(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1144)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
]]

[2020-09-14T18:59:33.477+0200] [Payara 5.2020.4] [ALLVARLIG] [NCLS-CORE-00016] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=22 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1600102767864] [timeMillis: 1600102773477] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  Startup service failed to start
MultiException stack 1 of 2
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.security.KeyStoreException: JCEKS not found
    at org.glassfish.security.services.impl.JCEKSPasswordAliasStore.containsKey(JCEKSPasswordAliasStore.java:169)
    at fish.payara.nucleus.microprofile.config.source.PasswordAliasConfigSource.getValue(PasswordAliasConfigSource.java:100)
    at fish.payara.nucleus.microprofile.config.spi.PayaraConfig.getSourceValue(PayaraConfig.java:183)
    at fish.payara.nucleus.microprofile.config.spi.PayaraConfig.getValueConverted(PayaraConfig.java:166)
    at fish.payara.nucleus.microprofile.config.spi.PayaraConfig.lambda$getValue$1(PayaraConfig.java:161)
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.compute(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1853)
    at fish.payara.nucleus.microprofile.config.spi.PayaraConfig.getValue(PayaraConfig.java:157)
    at fish.payara.nucleus.microprofile.config.spi.PayaraConfig.getValueInternal(PayaraConfig.java:127)
    at fish.payara.nucleus.microprofile.config.spi.PayaraConfig.getOptionalValue(PayaraConfig.java:123)
    at fish.payara.microprofile.healthcheck.HealthCheckService.postConstruct(HealthCheckService.java:139)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.ReflectionHelper.invoke(ReflectionHelper.java:1268)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.postConstructMe(ClazzCreator.java:309)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:351)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:463)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:281)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevelContext.findOrCreate(RunLevelContext.java:65)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2102)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:93)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:67)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.oneJob(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1213)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.run(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1144)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.security.KeyStoreException: JCEKS not found
    at org.glassfish.security.services.impl.JCEKSPasswordAliasStore.pa(JCEKSPasswordAliasStore.java:103)
    at org.glassfish.security.services.impl.JCEKSPasswordAliasStore.containsKey(JCEKSPasswordAliasStore.java:167)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: java.security.KeyStoreException: JCEKS not found
    at java.security.KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.java:851)
    at com.sun.enterprise.security.store.PasswordAdapter.loadKeyStore(PasswordAdapter.java:131)
    at com.sun.enterprise.security.store.PasswordAdapter.<init>(PasswordAdapter.java:110)
    at org.glassfish.security.services.impl.JCEKSPasswordAliasStore.pa(JCEKSPasswordAliasStore.java:101)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: JCEKS KeyStore not available
    at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:159)
    at java.security.Security.getImpl(Security.java:697)
    at java.security.KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.java:848)
    ... 31 more
MultiException stack 2 of 2
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: post construct on fish.payara.microprofile.healthcheck.HealthCheckService
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:369)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:463)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:281)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevelContext.findOrCreate(RunLevelContext.java:65)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2102)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:93)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:67)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.oneJob(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1213)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.run(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1144)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
]]

[2020-09-14T18:59:33.476+0200] [Payara 5.2020.4] [INFO] [NCLS-CORE-00101] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=21 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1600102767863] [timeMillis: 1600102773476] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Network Listener http-listener-1 started in: 21ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:8080]]]

[2020-09-14T18:59:33.513+0200] [Payara 5.2020.4] [INFO] [NCLS-CORE-00101] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=21 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1600102767863] [timeMillis: 1600102773513] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Network Listener http-listener-2 started in: 17ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:8181]]]

[2020-09-14T18:59:33.525+0200] [Payara 5.2020.4] [INFO] [NCLS-CORE-00101] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=21 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1600102767863] [timeMillis: 1600102773525] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Network Listener admin-listener started in: 6ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:4848]]]

[2020-09-14T18:59:33.526+0200] [Payara 5.2020.4] [INFO] [NCLS-CORE-00087] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=21 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1600102767863] [timeMillis: 1600102773526] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Grizzly 2.4.4 started in: 5,133ms - bound to [http-listener-1:8080, http-listener-2:8181, admin-listener:4848]]]

[2020-09-14T18:59:33.563+0200] [Payara 5.2020.4] [INFO] [NCLS-CORE-00101] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=23 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1600102767870] [timeMillis: 1600102773563] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Network Listener iiop-service started in: 6ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:3700]]]

[2020-09-14T18:59:33.590+0200] [Payara 5.2020.4] [INFO] [] [fish.payara.nucleus.hazelcast.HazelcastCore] [tid: _ThreadID=22 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1600102767864] [timeMillis: 1600102773590] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Hazelcast Instance Unbound from JNDI at payara/Hazelcast]]

[2020-09-14T18:59:33.595+0200] [Payara 5.2020.4] [INFO] [] [fish.payara.nucleus.hazelcast.HazelcastCore] [tid: _ThreadID=22 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1600102767864] [timeMillis: 1600102773595] [levelValue: 800] [[
  JSR107 Caching Provider Unbound from JNDI at payara/CachingProvider]]

[2020-09-14T18:59:33.595+0200] [Payara 5.2020.4] [INFO] [] [fish.payara.nucleus.hazelcast.HazelcastCore] [tid: _ThreadID=22 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1600102767864] [timeMillis: 1600102773595] [levelValue: 800] [[
  JSR107 Cache Manager Unbound from JNDI at payara/CacheManager]]

[2020-09-14T18:59:33.611+0200] [Payara 5.2020.4] [INFO] [NCLS-CORE-00101] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=87 _ThreadName=Executor-Service-10] [timeMillis: 1600102773611] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Network Listener http-listener-1 started in: 4ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:8080]]]

[2020-09-14T18:59:33.700+0200] [Payara 5.2020.4] [INFO] [NCLS-CORE-00101] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=87 _ThreadName=Executor-Service-10] [timeMillis: 1600102773700] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Network Listener http-listener-2 started in: 82ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:8181]]]

[2020-09-14T18:59:33.711+0200] [Payara 5.2020.4] [INFO] [NCLS-CORE-00101] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=87 _ThreadName=Executor-Service-10] [timeMillis: 1600102773711] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Network Listener admin-listener started in: 5ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:4848]]]

[2020-09-14T18:59:33.711+0200] [Payara 5.2020.4] [INFO] [NCLS-CORE-00087] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=87 _ThreadName=Executor-Service-10] [timeMillis: 1600102773711] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Grizzly 2.4.4 started in: 114ms - bound to [http-listener-1:8080, http-listener-2:8181, admin-listener:4848]]]

[2020-09-14T18:59:34.162+0200] [Payara 5.2020.4] [INFO] [] [fish.payara.nucleus.hazelcast.HazelcastCore] [tid: _ThreadID=22 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1600102767864] [timeMillis: 1600102774162] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Shutdown Hazelcast]]

[2020-09-14T18:59:34.164+0200] [Payara 5.2020.4] [ALLVARLIG] [NCLS-CORE-00014] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=1 _ThreadName=main] [timeMillis: 1600102774164] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  Shutdown required
MultiException stack 1 of 1
MultiException stack 1 of 2
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.security.KeyStoreException: JCEKS not found
    at org.glassfish.security.services.impl.JCEKSPasswordAliasStore.containsKey(JCEKSPasswordAliasStore.java:169)
    at fish.payara.nucleus.microprofile.config.source.PasswordAliasConfigSource.getValue(PasswordAliasConfigSource.java:100)
    at fish.payara.nucleus.microprofile.config.spi.PayaraConfig.getSourceValue(PayaraConfig.java:183)
    at fish.payara.nucleus.microprofile.config.spi.PayaraConfig.getValueConverted(PayaraConfig.java:166)
    at fish.payara.nucleus.microprofile.config.spi.PayaraConfig.lambda$getValue$1(PayaraConfig.java:161)
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.compute(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1853)
    at fish.payara.nucleus.microprofile.config.spi.PayaraConfig.getValue(PayaraConfig.java:157)
    at fish.payara.nucleus.microprofile.config.spi.PayaraConfig.getValueInternal(PayaraConfig.java:127)
    at fish.payara.nucleus.microprofile.config.spi.PayaraConfig.getOptionalValue(PayaraConfig.java:123)
    at fish.payara.microprofile.healthcheck.HealthCheckService.postConstruct(HealthCheckService.java:139)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.ReflectionHelper.invoke(ReflectionHelper.java:1268)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.postConstructMe(ClazzCreator.java:309)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:351)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:463)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:281)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevelContext.findOrCreate(RunLevelContext.java:65)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2102)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:93)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:67)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.oneJob(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1213)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.run(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1144)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.security.KeyStoreException: JCEKS not found
    at org.glassfish.security.services.impl.JCEKSPasswordAliasStore.pa(JCEKSPasswordAliasStore.java:103)
    at org.glassfish.security.services.impl.JCEKSPasswordAliasStore.containsKey(JCEKSPasswordAliasStore.java:167)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: java.security.KeyStoreException: JCEKS not found
    at java.security.KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.java:851)
    at com.sun.enterprise.security.store.PasswordAdapter.loadKeyStore(PasswordAdapter.java:131)
    at com.sun.enterprise.security.store.PasswordAdapter.<init>(PasswordAdapter.java:110)
    at org.glassfish.security.services.impl.JCEKSPasswordAliasStore.pa(JCEKSPasswordAliasStore.java:101)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: JCEKS KeyStore not available
    at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:159)
    at java.security.Security.getImpl(Security.java:697)
    at java.security.KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.java:848)
    ... 31 more
MultiException stack 2 of 2
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: post construct on fish.payara.microprofile.healthcheck.HealthCheckService
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:369)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:463)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:281)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevelContext.findOrCreate(RunLevelContext.java:65)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2102)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:93)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:67)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.oneJob(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1213)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.run(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1144)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
]]

[2020-09-14T18:59:34.166+0200] [Payara 5.2020.4] [ALLVARLIG] [] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=1 _ThreadName=main] [timeMillis: 1600102774166] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  Failed to start, exiting]]

[2020-09-14T18:59:34.166+0200] [Payara 5.2020.4] [INFO] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=1 _ThreadName=main] [timeMillis: 1600102774166] [levelValue: 800] [[
  FileMonitoring shutdown]]
```

EDIT*

I also created a brand new Java EE project with only the following class and I still get the same output from Payara

```
import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

@ApplicationPath("api")
public class CdiConfig extends Application {
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because your security provider doesn't support the JCEKS algorithm to open the Payara keystore. Try using a different distribution of Java, e.g. AdoptOpenJDK (https://adoptopenjdk.net/). It's possible that your Java doesn't support that algorithm.

The reason why Payara Server fails and GlassFish doesn't is that Payara Server attempts to find configuration values in password aliases, which are protected by the keystore. This results in an exception because it can't open the keystore. I bet that GlassFish would also fail to open the keystore if it needed it at some point later. GlassFish just doesn't have the functionality of reading the configuration from password aliases and thus doesn't attempt to open the keystore at startup.

Anyway, it's definitely a bug that this exception brings down the whole server. Payara Server should just ignore the configuration and go on. Raise this as a bug in Payara bug tracker: https://github.com/payara/Payara/issues.

Comment: Hi @Xenofono, you accepted this question as the correct answer. I'm curious, did it work with a different JDK? Which one? And for which one it didn't work in the first place?

Comment: Hi! Yes thank you for your help. I uninstalled Zulu openjdk 14 and Openjdk 8 since I got neither to work.

Then I installed Oracle JDK 1.8 and it worked straight away.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. Payara Server isn't yet tested against Java 14 and there are some issues with it. It should work on OpenJDK 8 though, but different Linux distributions make custom changes to OpenJDK so it's hard to predict the behavior. It's safer to use OpenJDK 8 or 11, Zulu JDK 8 or 11, or AdoptOpenJDK 8 or 11 (Adopt OpenJDK is a vanilla OpenJDK but tested by the AdoptOpenJDK consortium).